# Compilation error on While(scan.hasNext()), it says "; expected"

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm getting an error off of a segment of code which came from this forum.

```
While(scan.hasNext()) {

}
```

It says

> ';' expected

Please direct me in the right direction.

Comment: One of the most important things you learn in programming is the following: The content of an error is important. "An error" is no use to you or I, but an error saying "The coffee is cold" tells you that you may have neglected to switch the kettle on. In other words, what is the error? Also, can you provide a MWE (minimal working example) rather than the full code in context? (Often, producing a MWE results in you seeing the problem yourself).

Comment: at the line : While(scan.hasNext())  I get an error when i hover over it it says ';' expected, when I hit alt-enter it tells me, "create method while(boolean) in Rolodex2.contactController.....I posted all the code for context since i am very unsure of my coding abilities...

Comment: I strongly recommend to pause the current Java EE / JSF project and take some time apart to learn basic Java first before diving into Java EE. Oracle has very nice tutorials. Hover the `[java]` tag on the question and click the *info* link to find useful links. If you're unable to interpret or research basic Java compilation errors, you're not ready for Java EE.

Comment: Nice comment as I'm in week 6 of an 8 week course, so thats not going to happen...The problem with these courses is it is go read this assignemnt, then write this project code....no examples are given no video tutorials, either get it or you dont....and I did the Java 200 course last summer...these aren't the topics we covered in java

Comment: `@ManagedBean(name = "contactController")`, `@SessionScoped`, `@RequestScoped`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you've used 'While' instead of 'while' (it's case sensitive).

Your IDE has recognised that the **method** While doesn't exist, and has created it (unimplemented). It thinks that While is a method, makes that method, and then expects it to have the syntax of that method - of course, "while" is a construct and has a different syntax.

Comment: I'm not doing the downgrading, I'd like to increase it but i dont have enough points.  You were right on the money, and sadly this was a product of 36hour operation with no sleep.  I'm in the military and deployed to AFG so I'm having major struggles....

Comment: Don't worry, it was just a bit of a shock that less than a second after I answered, the downvote appeared! Your question has been edited by @BalusC to highlight the important section of the code so that it is useful to others who search for a similar problem. Good luck with the rest of your learning process! If you can switch off the automatic method creation in your IDE, I highly recommend you do so. For now, at least.